# Is it possible to import messages into the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there the possibility to import a list of SMS messages into the Android emulator for testing purposes?

Comment: @m0skit0 Sending an SMS to the emulator is _completely_ different than importing SMSs to the emulator.  I do not get _any_ results involving importing, what this question is asking.

Comment: @m0skit0 did you really read my question before linking something totally unrelated? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Here's how:

1. Download "SMS Backup and Restore.apk" file from [here](http://handheld.softpedia.com/progDownload/SMS-Backup-Restore-Download-92446.html)
2. Install the apk on your phone, or use google play.
3. Export your SMS messages on your phone and share the XML backup file to your computer, either email it yourself or if you move the app to your sdcard before you backup you can fetch the XML file off the sdcard by copying it to your computer.
4. Copy or move downloaded apk file to platform-tools folder in your android-skd folder.
5. Windows: Run `cmd` and change into `platform-tools` dir.
6. Type `adb -s emulator_name install "SMS Backup and Restore.apk"`.
7. Now change to DDMS mode in Eclipse and create a folder called `SMSBackupRestore` under `mnt/sdcard` so it would end up being `mnt/sdcard/SMSBackupRestore`.
8. Run Backup and Restore app in the emulator and import the XML file...Done!

Comment: All the steps work. But opening "Messaging" app will not show the SMS messages.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about importing SMS messages from an existing file into an emulator. However, what i do know is that you could spoof text messages via DDMS. You could do that and then start up your app to do the magical things you want to do. [Android Dev - Using DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an app such as SMS Backup and Restore, and make an archive of your own text messages. It saves it out as XML, so you could always modify it if you wanted to. Then, just install that app onto the emulator (I'm assuming you can install 3rd party apps on the emulator, but I'm not certain), and then restore from that XML file.

Comment: I thought about that too, but I thought that it wasn't possible to install 3rd party apps on the emulator.

Comment: I think you can't through the market...SMS Backup and Restore is free, I believe, so you might be able to pull and transfer the APK and install it that way. (after enabling off-market downloads in the Development settings). I don't know that it'll work, but worth a try!